# JavaScript exponentiation unary operator design decision

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence, exponentiation, ecmascript-2016

So I was fooling around with the new exponentiation operator and I discovered you cannot put a unary operator immediately before the base number.

```
let result = -2 ** 2; // syntax error
let result = -(2 ** 2); // -4
let x = 3;
let result = --x ** 2; // 4
```

From the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**)):

> In JavaScript, it is impossible to write an ambiguous exponentiation expression, i.e. you cannot put a unary operator (`+`/`-`/`~`/`!`/`delete`/`void`/`typeof`) immediately before the base number.
>
> In most languages like PHP and Python and others that have an exponentiation operator (typically `^` or `**`), the exponentiation operator is defined to have a higher precedence than unary operators such as unary `+` and unary `-`, but there are a few exceptions. For example, in Bash the `**` operator is defined to have a lower precedence than unary operators.

I understand this was made an error by design. I don't understand this design decision. Who's really going to be surprised that `-x ** 2` is negative? This follows not only other mainstream programming languages but a mathematical notation that has been in common use for hundreds of years and is taught to every high school algebra student.

In Javascript `'1'+ 2` is `'12'` and `'1'-2` is `-1` but `-1**2` raises an error because it could be ambiguous? Help me understand this design decision.

Comment: Writing `-x ** 2` instead of `- x**2` would make it ambiguous alone.

Comment: Well, I believe I was always taught at school that -x raised to the power of y produces a positive number. So, -1**2 should produce 1. At least this is what I believe was taught, and I am sufficiently confident that my belief is correct.

Comment: Why the heck was this question downvoted ?

Comment: @doubleOrt - Agreed, very strange (about the vote). BTW, in math, `-1²` is `-1`. It's `-(1²)`, not `(-1)²`. I went 'round and 'round in my head on that one and finally [punted and asked the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3027197/165692). It's been **that** long since math class. But I'm also a bit embarrassed to have asked, since I routinely see things like `-2³² + 1` and have no trouble interpreting that correctly (2³² = 4294967296, -4294967296 + 1 is -4294967295).

Comment: @T.J._Crowder I am actually quite ashamed of my comment now that I read it, -1**2 only takes a basic understanding of operator precedence in Math, and "(-x)" raised to the power of "y" does not always produce a positive.

Comment: The question is "lame" -- in that one can make arguments in either direction to support ones desired outcome.  Ex: find a calculator with a exponent or squaring function.  Type in -2 and square it.  or raise it to '2'. I think you would be hard pressed to find one that came up with -4 as an answer.  Negative numbers were around long before "operators", let alone "unary ones".  Yet from a practical point of view, why would same calculator allow -2**1 and -2**2, but not -2**1.5.  See, you can justify it either way!  "Lame"...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I don't understand this design decision.

Read more about it at https://esdiscuss.org/topic/exponentiation-operator-precedence, https://esdiscuss.org/topic/power-operator-why-does-2-3-throws, https://github.com/rwaldron/tc39-notes/blob/master/es7/2015-09/sept-23.md#exponentiation-operator and https://github.com/rwaldron/tc39-notes/blob/master/es7/2015-09/sept-24.md#exponentiation-operator.

> Who's really going to be surprised that `-x ** 2` is negative?

Enough people to matter. Some relevant quotes from the above resources:

- "*making `**` bind tighter than unary operators would break `x**-2`. And making it sometimes tighter and sometimes looser would be too confusing and lead to other opportunities for precedence inversion.*" - [Waldemar Horwat](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2015-August/044012.html)
- "*Given the conflict between the history of `**` in other languages, [and] the general pattern that unary binds tighter than binary, any solution at this point will confuse many people.*" - [Mark S. Miller](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2015-August/044018.html)
- "*acknowledge the prospect of significant whitespace: `-x**2 === -(x ** 2)` and `-x ** 2 === (-x) ** 2`*" - [Alexander Jones](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2015-August/044083.html)
- "*The problem is, however rare unary minus before an exponentiation expression may be, the lack of superscript-with-smaller-font sugests that `-` binds tighter than `**`. And indeed apart from dot (a special form whose right operand must be a lexical identifier-name) and square brackets (which isn't an infix operator per se), unary operators bind tighter than binary in JS as in C and other C-derived languages.*" - [Brendan Eich](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2015-September/044232.html)
- "*For math it seems obvious that `-52`. But for `-5 ** 2`, because of the whitespace around the infix operator. Even without space, `-` seems to be part of the literal.*" - Dave Herman
- [Regarding programming language precedence], "*effectively zero people have an intutition about this from other languages. Agree people have an itutition that `**` is the exponentiation operator. But people usually try to avoid dark corners so they never develop an intuition for negative bases.*" - Dave Herman

> In Javascript `'1'+ 2` is `'12'` and `'1'-2` is `-1` but `-1**2` raises an error because it could be ambiguous?

Well they put considerably more effort in the design of extensions to the language today :-) It's the best solution that they could *reach consensus* for.