# ECMAScript 2020 Exponentiation Grammar confusion

Tags: javascript, grammar

Checking the latest standard for ECMA-262 ECMAScript 2020 (or 11th Edition) and couldn't figure out the grammar production for exponentiation.

> ```
> UpdateExpression[Yield, Await]:
>  LeftHandSideExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
>  LeftHandSideExpression[?Yield, ?Await][no LineTerminator here]++
>  LeftHandSideExpression[?Yield, ?Await][no LineTerminator here]--
>  ++UnaryExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
>  --UnaryExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
>
> UnaryExpression[Yield, Await]:
>  UpdateExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
>  delete UnaryExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
>  void UnaryExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
>  typeof UnaryExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
>  +UnaryExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
>  -UnaryExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
>  ~UnaryExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
>  !UnaryExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
>  [+Await]AwaitExpression[?Yield]
>
> ExponentiationExpression[Yield, Await]:
>  UnaryExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
>  UpdateExpression[?Yield, ?Await]**ExponentiationExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
> ```

So a UnaryExpression is an ExponentiationExpression thus allowing something like -x to pass up the parsing tree but to actually evaluate an exponentiation the LHS has to be an UpdateExpression (++x, --x, x++, x-- or just x). The RHS is an ExponentiationExpression so can therefore be a UnaryExpression. This means that parsing x ** -y is easy but how do you parse -x ** y. I thought of treating it as -(x ** y) but then had no way to get the unparenthesized x ** y from being an Expression back to an UpdateExpression to feed into UnaryExpression.

Or is it simply that -x ** y is disallowed and you have to get explicit by using

-(x ** y)

or

(-x) ** y

, both of which are easy to parse as follows:

(x ** y) is a ParenthesizedExpression so feeds in to UnaryExpression as a PrimaryExpression.

(-x) similarly feeds into UpdateExpression as a PrimaryExpression

Or am I missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

> Or is it simply that -x ** y is disallowed and you have to get explicit by using
>
> ```
> -(x ** y)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> (-x) ** y
> ```

Precisely.

> Or am I missing something obvious.

No, you got it right.

There are some useful links in [this answer to a related question from 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47069790/1566221), including [this email thread started by Brendan Eich](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2015-September/044232.html) on the es-discuss list in 2015, which proposes the current syntax.

Some concrete examples:

From the Firefox console:

```
-2**4
SyntaxError: unparenthesized unary expression can't appear on the left-hand side of '**'
```

From [David Flanagan's "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide"](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/9781491952016/) (O'Reilly) (not an endorsement):

> There is a natural ambiguity to expressions like `-3 ** 2`. Depending on the relative precedence of unary minus and exponentiation, that expression could mean `(-3)**2` or `-(3**2)`. Different languages handle this differently, and rather than pick sides, JavaScript simply makes it a syntax error to omit parentheses in this case, forcing you to write an unambiguous expression.

Of course, the real definitive guide is the grammar, which you have already quoted.